# camlp4 is not properly installed for OCaml 4.05.0 using opam

Tags: ocaml

All opam packages that depend on camlp4 are not installing properly on my system.

This file is missing:

```
.opam/system/bin/camlp4of: not found
```

But running `opam install camlp4` gives

```
[NOTE] Package camlp4 is already installed (current version is 4.05+system).
```

Listing content

```
$ ls ~/.opam/system/bin/
dune  jbuilder  menhir  ocaml  ocamlbuild  ocamlbuild.byte  ocamlbuild.native  ocamlfind  octavius  opam-depext  ppx-base  ppx-jane  safe_camlp4
```

So `safe_camlp4` is there, but not camlp4?

My system is a RockPro64 running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. Any ideas?

Comment: Hi, camlp4 has been deprecated for a long time, is there any way you can use PPX (the current recommended OCaml metaprogramming system) instead? Btw, I don't know if this is the right thing to do, but I would try symlinking `safe_camlp4` to `camlp4of` and see if that works.

Comment: My code-base is an old project of mine, didn't try to compile it for some years. Can I opam switch to another version, OCaml 3.something?

Comment: You can try switching to an OCaml version which you're sure worked. Another option is to switch to camlp5, a community-maintained continuation of the camlp series: https://github.com/camlp4/camlp4/

Comment: Hm, OCaml can't guess my host (ARM).

Comment: @Yawar Any idea how to tell opam to switch arch? Didn't find it in the manual page.

Comment: As far as I know it defaults to the arch of the machine it's running on. Cross-compiling is possible but will take some setup https://github.com/ocaml-cross